# Easy javascript if and else. If url is return and else scroll to anhor

Tags: javascript, scroll, tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (location.href == "http://www.mysitemain.com")
{
return false;
} 

else 

{

window.onload = function() {
var el = document.getElementById('wrap');
el.scrollIntoView(true);
}

}
</script>
```

Anyone can help me fix this code ? Trying to make something like if the site url then return false else go to anchor

Comment: Check what the actual value of `location.href` is on that page; I'd bet you get a trailing slash

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a "return" statement; your code isn't in a function.  Just test for the URL being *not* equal to the string:

```
if (location.href != "http://www.mysitemain.com") {
  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('wrap').scrollIntoView(true);
  };
}
```